# MVC3 Custom Unobtrusive Validator on a List of Objects

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, validation, unobtrusive-validation

The basic question to start: How can you put a custom, unobtrusive validator ontop of a list of objects within your model? Like, say my model allows multiple file uploads, and thus I have a list of files, and I want my validator to run on each of those files?

Now for a specific example. I've got a custom, unobtrusive validator that checks to see if a file extension is not within a list of prohibited extensions:

```
public class FileExtensionValidatorAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable {

    protected static string[] PROHIBITED_EXTENSIONS = {
        // ... List of extensions I don't allow.
    };

    public override bool IsValid(object value) {
        if (value is IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase>) {
            foreach (var file in (IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase>)value) {
                var fileName = file.FileName;
                if (PROHIBITED_EXTENSIONS.Any(x => fileName.EndsWith(x))) return false;
            }
        } else {
            var file = (HttpPostedFileBase)value;
            var fileName = file.FileName;
            if (PROHIBITED_EXTENSIONS.Any(x => fileName.EndsWith(x))) return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context) {
        var modelClientVlidationRule = new ModelClientValidationRule {
            ErrorMessage = this.ErrorMessageString,
            ValidationType = "fileextension",
        };
        modelClientVlidationRule.ValidationParameters.Add("prohibitedextensions", string.Join("|", PROHIBITED_EXTENSIONS));

        yield return modelClientVlidationRule;
    }
}
```

Take note in my IsValid that I built this to accept a single file or a list of files.

In my model class, I can make use of this on a single HttpPostedFileBase:

```
[FileExtensionValidator(ErrorMessage = "Invalid Extension")]
public HttpPostedFileBase Upload { get; set; }
```

Then I attach to jquery's validator in my view:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("fileExtension", function (value, element, param) {
    var extension = "";
    var dotIndex = value.lastIndexOf('.');
    if (dotIndex != -1) extension = value.substring(dotIndex + 1).toLowerCase();

    return $.inArray(extension, param.prohibitedExtensions) === -1;
});

jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add('fileextension', ['prohibitedextensions'], function (options) {
    options.rules['fileExtension'] = {
        prohibitedExtensions: options.params.prohibitedextensions.split('|')
    };
    options.messages['fileExtension'] = options.message;
});
```

This all works great, client side and server side ...but only on a single HttpPostedFileBase. The problem is that I need to provide users the ability to upload one or more files. If I change my model to this:

```
[FileExtensionValidator(ErrorMessage = "Invalid Extension")]
public List<HttpPostedFileBase> Uploads { get; set; }
```

...the Client-side validation no longer runs; only the server-side works. This is evident when doing a view-source. The <input> tag that gets generated is missing all the data-val attributes it needs to run. In doing a debug, GetClientValidationRules is never called.

What am I missing?

Could this be because of how I render it? I'm simply using an EditorTemplate for HttpPostedFileBase:

```
@model System.Web.HttpPostedFileBase
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m, new { type = "file", size = 60 })
```

...and my view renders it like this:

```
<p>@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Uploads)</p>
```

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Is your view rendering multiple textboxes?  Where/how are the values being stored on the client after upload?

Comment: Yes. The multiple textboxes are rendering ok and they're uploading ok to the server. (The server-side validation does run correctly on the both of them.) But, sorry, I don't understand your second question.

Comment: Can you upload a couple files and use a DOM inspector to show the rendered HTML?

Comment: If you mean after posting back my uploads to the server, I don't have a view (yet) for that; I confirm the server side validation works just through the debugger. If you mean inspecting the DOM after I attach a file but before I upload, yeah I can. I think the problem is that, before I even attach, the input tag has no "data-val" attributes at all. Where-as all the other client-validated fields do. ie, this is what's rendered: <input name="Assets[0]" class="valid" id="Assets_0_" type="file" size="60" value="" />. jquery is adding class="valid" to it, oddly, though my js code isn't running.

Comment: The validator plugin uses the field **name** to associate rules. You may want to create a custom rule for `Assets[*]` named fields or force a specific validation at the time the form is submit.

Comment: I'll try, but what about the server-side? GetClientValidationRules isn't being called, and thus my "prohibitedextensions" are not rendering to HTML, and thus not passed to jquery. eg, when using a single HttpPostedFileBase, this is the rendered HTML: <input name="Asset" id="Asset" type="file" size="60" data-val="true" data-val-fileextension-prohibitedextensions="(my list)" data-val-fileextension="Invalid Extension" value=""/>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what I came up with.

I actually think the problem is ultimately caused because MVC doesn't know that I want that Data Annotation on the List to be applied to all of its members. Nor should it I suppose.

So I simply made a "viewmodel" wrapper around HttpPostedFileBase, and put my validator there:

```
public class UploadedFile {
    [FileExtensionValidator(ErrorMessage = "Invalid Extension")]
    public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }
}
```

Then, in my actual model, I now just use a list of those instead:

```
public List<UploadedFile> Uploads { get; set; }
```

...with no more dataannotations here of course since they're now in UploadedFile.

Then, with minor modifications to the view and editortemplate to use these, this now works a-ok, client side and server side. (Still, feels clunky to me. If anyone has a simpler way I'm still happy to hear it.)